# Trying to find a way to get 3 year multiple entry Schengen Visa to be able to visit German boyfriend and his Family

Tags: schengen, pakistani-citizens, long-stay-visas

I wish I can find some answers or tips here that google has concealed. I am an undergraduate student in Italy and planning to move to the UK next year (Pakistani Passport), but whilst that I’d also like to maintain a long term Schengen Visa because I travel a lot and also my boyfriend is from Germany and go there often to see him. Our relationship is not registered anywhere so it is unofficial for fitting the few given criteria and I would like to find out if I can fit in some category to apply for a long term visa and not have the pain to apply for short term visas every once in a while. Does anybody have any experience on that? I’m basically just trying to find a way to have one leg in Schengen and the other in the UK. Many thanks.

Comment: As we do not yet know whether and when Brexit is going to happen and how it will work out for border crossing rules with Schengen countries, not for people with non UK/Schengen passports for sure, with some doubts for those who are from either area, we can not guaranty any results right now.

Comment: @Willeke I don't see how Brexit would affect this.  Am I missing something?

Comment: OP is talking about moving to the UK (from Italy now) and wants to visit the Schengen area on a regular basis. I see Brexit related problems.

Comment: @Willeke other than the possibility of issues with airline licensing (which will surely be very temporary if they occur at all), I’m still struggling to understand what impact Brexit could have on a Pakistani citizen’s ability to visit Germany.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, Schengen visa with long validity and multiple entries are given after a few visits on shorter, single-entry visa without overstays or incidents. Your previous Italian visa should count in your favor.

It might become problematic if your ties to your place of residence (the UK) become weak.

Comment: This is the most realistic option. Give as reason visits and travel 3-4 times a year. Remember that the 90/180 days rule will then apply. It would then be up to the consulate to deside how long the multiple visa is valid.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience (with over 6 multiple entry schengen visa's with Sri Lankan passport), the more you traveled to and out of the schengen zone the higher the chance of applying and getting a long term visa. I visited my gf in Budapest so many times, and actually ended up getting a residence permit for "other purpose" by showing our bank accounts, employment etc in Hungary. But I didn't renew it as I have to come back home often for work (since there is a permit stipulation which states I can't be out for more than 3-6 month per period, and I couldn't obviously fulfill that due to work and other travel). So I simply ended up applying for a long term 3 year visa and got it. Again with a letter from my gf, both our employment docs. Wasn't an issue, and got it approved in 5 working days due to my visa history.